# Get outside variables into image.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get image dimensions and afterwards perform more actions. As image onload is asynchronous I have decided to do everything in the onload call. This is what I have right now:

```
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); };
}
```

// ajax response this some info:

```
function(res) {
    var totalFound = res.data.length;
    var photo = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < totalFound; i++) {
        var full = res.data[i].urls.raw;
        var thumb = res.data[i].urls.thumb;
        var user = res.data[i].user.name;
        var links = res.data[i].user.links.html;

        getMeta(thumb,function(width, height) { 
            console.log(width + 'px ' + height + 'px') 

            photo.push({
                full: full,
                thumb: thumb,
                user: author,
                link: links
                width: this.width
            });
        });
    };
};
```

The problem is that variables full, thumb, user and links are not available in the getMeta callback. How to get over this?

Comment: In addition to the solution in the answer, `user: author` should be `user: user`, `link: links` is missing a comma, and `this.width` should be `width`: https://jsfiddle.net/qdnw9f5w/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those variables are scoped outside the `for` loop, meaning they're updated, rather than declared, in every successive iteration and every callback will see the final state of them since they're all invoked some time after the `for` loop has completed.

If you replace your `for` loop with a `forEach`, you will create a new scope for each iteration and the variables will be scoped the way you want them to:

```
function(res) {
    var photo = [];

    res.data.forEach(function(item) {
        var full = item.urls.raw;
        var thumb = item.urls.thumb;
        var user = item.user.name;
        var links = item.user.links.html;

        getMeta(thumb,function(width, height) { 
            console.log(width + 'px ' + height + 'px') 

            photo.push({
                full: full,
                thumb: thumb,
                user: author,
                link: links,
                width: this.width
            });
        });
    });
};
```

If you have the option of using ES6 syntax, an alternative is to simply use `let` instead of `var` which will properly scope the variables to each iteration.